# Catch a Runtime Exception thrown from ActionListener in a Waiting Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I am working on a Uni project to implement a Texas Hold'em poker game. I have been working on a way to to halt the game while waiting for user input (from GUI) if no input is received then the player will be folded. 
My initial code just called `sleep()` on the game thread and then `notify()` from the controller. The problem I ran into with this method was I had no way to tell if the controller had notified or the that sleep had ended. 
To try and flag this I had the controller throw a `RuntimeException` but have had alot of trouble trying to catch this exception at the game thread.

Here is my minimum viable example:

**GUI.java**

```
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    private JButton jb;
    private JPanel jp;
    private WaitTest wt;

    public GUI(WaitTest wt) throws HeadlessException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.wt = wt;
        jp = new JPanel();
        jb = new JButton("Throw Runtime");
        jp.add(jb);
        jb.addActionListener(new TestController(wt));
        this.add(jp);
        pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public GUI(GraphicsConfiguration gc)
    {
        super(gc);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public GUI(String title) throws HeadlessException
    {
        super(title);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public GUI(String title, GraphicsConfiguration gc)
    {
        super(title, gc);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

**TestController.java**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TestController implements ActionListener
{
    private WaitTest wt;

    public TestController(WaitTest wt)
    {
        this.wt = wt;
    }

    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Controller throws runtime");
        synchronized(wt.getT())
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Runtime flying");
        }
    }
}
```

**WaitTest.java**

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class WaitTest implements Runnable
{
    private Thread t;

    public WaitTest()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.t = new Thread();
    }

    public Thread getT()
    {
        return t;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println("Player folded");
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            System.out.println("Caught ");
        }

        System.out.println("interupt not received");

    }

    public void test() throws InterruptedException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        synchronized (t)
        {
            Future<?> future = executor.submit(this);
            try
            {
                future.get();
            }
            catch (ExecutionException e)
            {
                System.out.println("hooray!! runtime caught");
                t.notify();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Runtime caught");
                t.notify();
                return;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Driver.java**

```
public class driver
{

    public driver()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WaitTest wt = new WaitTest();
        GUI gui = new GUI(wt);
        wt.test();
        gui.repaint();

    }
}
```

The runtime Exception is never caught is there a simple way to catch this? or is there a better way to stop the game loop and wait for input? This is my first attempt at thread control/concurrency so I am probably overlooking something simple

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by converting WaitTest to extend TimerTask (which implements Runnable) and changing `Thread()` to `Timer()`.

Then in the controller instead of needing to throw a Runtime Exception I just called `cancel()` on the timer

This is much cleaner for my purposes the mucking about with Executors and exceptions

WaitTest.java now looks like this:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class WaitTest extends TimerTask
{
    private Timer t;

    public WaitTest()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.t = new Timer(true);
    }
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Player folded");

    }

    public void test()
    {
        // Schedule task for 5 sec time unless the 
        // controller cancels
        t.schedule(this, 5000);

    }

    public Timer getT()
    {
        return t;
    }

}
```